# What does "repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 2 " mean?

Tags: replit, exitstatus

I cannot run any code that I write, it just says that "repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 2 " but it does not indicate mistake in any line.

I tried to undo the lines I wrote up to the point when the file worked normally and then I wrote some basic functions like print or input but that also didn't work. It seems like I cannot run any file right now.